# Executor Memory vs Java Heap Size memory

Tags: java, apache-spark, jvm

My cluster size is 3 nodes  having `8 GB RAM` and `2 core` each.I am increasing the executor memory in following way for spark :

```
//creating spark session
    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName(s"${this.getClass.getSimpleName}")
      .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "9")
      .config("spark.executor.memory", "3g")
      .config("spark.executor.cores", "1")
      .master("local[*]")
      .getOrCreate()
```

Thus 4 executor with 3gigs of RAM each will launch having one task per core.

The code i am executing here is as follows:

```
val seq2 = List((125,0),(125,125),(125,250),(125,375))

val urls = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(seq2).toDF()

val actual_data = urls.map(x => HTTPRequestParallel.ds(x.getInt(0).toString,x.getInt(1).toString,t0)).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)

val dataframe = spark.read.option("header","true").json(actual_data)
```

When i am calling 4 web-api in parallel which is returning around 1 gigs of data per call which is getting serialized in one method,i am still getting `java heap memory` issue.

As i know api is synchronized call,so it will be fetching and storing incoming data somewhere.Where is that location,is it jvm heap memory of node or executor memory assigned?

Comment: Why are you trying to persist everything before you want to trigger your processing? The issue is the persist is eating up your memory

Comment: actually to calculate time of api execution,i am persisting it so that action happens and call to api gets executed.Thus in this way i am able to map execution time of executor with api response time

Comment: Instead of persisting can you write it to a partitioned table? And then you can read the data. This way it would reduce the load on spark.

Comment: Thanks constantine.Then where it is persisting data in this case.I have mentioned strategy as disk and memory,so as per my understanding it should ideally be storing on both and heap error should not come..

Comment: You never get entire executor memory for caching. You can watch the video on Unified Memory Model here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dPHrykZL8Cg&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 0):

Increase `shuffle.partition` to 1000 or more, It should resolve the issue.

Also you can try using `spark.default.parallelism`.

Comment: This wont solve his issue. His job is having memory issue due to the persist